# pass multiple outputs to a different module in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to cover each parts as modules rather than keeping it in a single main.tf file.
My intention is to create 1 vnet (TESTVNET), multiple subnets, NIC's for each subnet.

I'm able to reach till creating multiple subnets in my Vnet. What I'm looking for is on how to pass the subnet ID's to NETWORKINTERFACE module. Please find my code below;

Main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = var.RGname
  location = var.RGlocation
}

module "VNET" {
  source              = "./Modules/NetworkConfig"
  name                = var.VNETname
  address_space       = var.address_space
  location            = var.RGlocation
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
}

module "SUBNETS" {
  source               = "./Modules/SubnetConfig"
  Subnetlist           = var.Subnetlist
  virtual_network_name = module.VNET.vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  depends_on           = [azurerm_resource_group.resource_group, module.VNET.vnet]

}

module "NETWORKINTERFACE" {
  source              = "./Modules/NIConfig"
  niclist             = var.niclist
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
```

SUBNET.tf

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "SUBNETS" {
for_each=var.Subnetlist
name=each.value.name
address_prefixes=[each.value.address]
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
}

output "subnet_ids" {
   value = values(azurerm_subnet.SUBNETS)[*].id
}
```

NETWORKINTERFACE.tf

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "NETWORKINTERFACE" {
  for_each=var.niclist
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig1"
    subnet_id                     =   # part where I'm confused
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

How can I pass the output values from Subnet module (3 subnet in total=3 id's) to NETWORKINTERFACE module, where it should take each of these id's in `for_each=var.niclist` loop.
If you find this approach incorrect, let me know

PS. I'm new to terraform

-- update 2

please find my tfvars

```
RGlocation = "westus"
RGname     = "TEST-RG1-TERRAFORM"
VNETname      = "TEST-VNET-TERRAFORM"
address_space = "10.0.0.0/16"
Subnetlist = {
  "s1" = { name = "TESTSUBNET1-TERRAFORM", address = "10.0.1.0/24" },
  "s2" = { name = "TESTSUBNET2-TERRAFORM", address = "10.0.2.0/24" },
  "s3" = { name = "TESTSUBNET3-TERRAFORM", address = "10.0.3.0/24" }
}

niclist = {
  "s1" = { name = "TESTNIC1-TERRAFORM" },
  "s2" = { name = "TESTNIC2-TERRAFORM" },
  "s3" = { name = "TESTNIC3-TERRAFORM" }
}
```

this is how the variable is populated. I have used the suggestion from @martin and modified few commands. It is now creating subnets and NIC's the way I wanted.

Main.tf

```
module "VNET" {
  source              = "./Modules/NetworkConfig"
  name                = var.VNETname
  address_space       = var.address_space
  location            = var.RGlocation
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
}

module "SUBNETS" {
  source               = "./Modules/SubnetConfig"
  Subnetlist           = var.Subnetlist
  virtual_network_name = module.VNET.vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  depends_on           = [azurerm_resource_group.resource_group, module.VNET.vnet]

}

module "NETWORKINTERFACE" {
  source = "./Modules/NIConfig"
  
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  nics = tomap({
    for k, subnet_id in module.SUBNETS.subnet_ids : k => {
      name      = var.niclist[k].name
      subnet_id = subnet_id
    }
  })
}
```

SUBNETS.tf

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "SUBNETS" {
for_each=var.Subnetlist
name=each.value.name
address_prefixes=[each.value.address]
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
}

output "subnet_ids" {
  value = tomap({ for k, s in azurerm_subnet.SUBNETS : k => s.id })
}
```

NETWORKINTERFACE.tf

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "NETWORKINTERFACE" {
  for_each=var.nics
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig1"
    subnet_id                     =  each.value.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `for_each` across multiple resources and modules like this it's important to preserve the tracking keys of the objects so that Terraform can see which instances of one resource correlate with instances of another and with the intermediate data structures that you use to pass the data around.

In your case, that would mean changing the shape of the `subnet_ids` output value to be a map from subnet key to subnet ID, rather than just the subnet IDs alone, so that it's clear which ID belongs to which subnet key:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "all" {
  for_each = var.Subnetlist

  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.address]
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
}

output "subnet_ids" {
 value = tomap({ for k, s in azurerm_subnet.all : k => s.id })
}
```

Your network interface module seems to have an input variable `niclist` whose declaration you didn't show, but I'm assuming it'll look something like this, and I'm going to rename it to `nics` because I'm changing it to be a map instead:

```
variable "nics" {
  type = map(
    object({
      name      = string
      subnet_id = string
    })
  )
}
```

You can then use that variable as the basis for your `for_each` of network interfaces:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "all" {
  for_each = var.nics

  name                = each.value.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig1"
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

The remaining problem then is how to build the value of the `nics` input variable from inside the root module. You haven't shown how the root module's `niclist` variable is populated, and so I don't know how NICs and subnets are related. Since you showed a configuration which suggests one NIC per subnet, perhaps it would be sufficient to derive the `nics` variable value directly from the subnets map and remove `var.niclist` altogether:

```
module "network_interface" {
  source              = "./Modules/NIConfig"

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  nics = tomap({
    for k, subnet_id in module.subnets.subnet_ids : k => {
      name      = k
      subnet_id = subnet_id
    }
  })
}
```

---

NOTE: The naming scheme you're currently using doesn't match usual Terraform idiom and so I changed some of the names in my answer here to use the standard style of all-lowercase names with words separated by underscores. I would suggest following the standard naming scheme so that your configuration will be intuitive to future maintainers who might already have Terraform experience from elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, Please find the tfvars in update2 section above, where I defining nic names in tfvars.
I have made the changes in code accordingly and is working the way i'm expecting it to. Is it okay if I ask you to have a look above and let me know if my method is okay to proceed, or should I try anything else?

Comment: Combining the subnet ids with the NIC names by correlating by keys as you did in what you shared in your question seems like a fine approach to me. You could consider combining those both into a single input variable of type `map(object({ subnet_name = string, nic_name = string }))` so that the keys are _forced_ to match, but that's just a style thing and what you did already is okay too.